# (JAVA) How to make a class have an instance of another (abstract) class, then to pass instance to multiple objects?

Tags: java, class, object, instance, abstract

So as the title says, I have a class, Game and it needs to have an instance of an abstract GameState (which is extended).
Game then needs to pass this instance to several Player objects.
For Instance:

```
public class PlayGame {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Player red = new EasyPlayer()
    Player green = new HardPlayer()

    Game game = new Game(red, green)
    game.play();
  }
}
```

If anyone could help with what code I need to put in Game (including the constructor) it would be very appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all abstract class cant have a constructor so it's imposible "to have an instance of an abstract class". Abstract class it's like interface but with implemented methods.

Answer (score 1):

Meybe you need something like this:

```
public class Game{
    protected GameState state;
    public Game(Colllection<Player> players){
        for(Player p: players)
            p.setGemeState(state);   
    }
}
```